# Find Daily occurrence based on given past occurrence frequency

Tags: math, average

I am trying to find average daily occurrence based on given occurrence frequency for last 7 days, 14 days, 30 days, 60 days and 90 days.
For ex below is the data for two events for last 7,14,30,60, 90 days.

### | Event | 7 Days | 14 Days | 30 Days | 60 Days | 90 Days |

| 1    | 2 times| 4 times | 8 times |18 times |19 times |

|2     | 3 times | 6 times | 7 times | 10 times | 11 times |

is it as simple as [((2/7)+(4/14)+(8/30)+(18/60)+(19/90))/5] for first event ?

This can also be thought in terms of item 1 and item 2 with their selling frequency in 7/14/30/60/90 days and we need to find out daily sale for each item.

Answer (score 0):

Daily average in the last n days = (Total number of events in last n days)/(n)
For Event 1:
If you want find daily average in the last 7 days, it will be 2/7, in the last 14 days will be 4/14 etc. However, if you want to find the overall daily average you would have:
Overall daily average = (Total number of events)/(Total number of days)

For Event 1 that would be 19/90 which is same as daily average in the last 90 days.

The expression you wrote does not have any meaning. Note that last 14 days includes last 7 days etc.